# Redux-form validation breaks when using multiple components with the same form name

Tags: redux-form

I run into the validation issue using multiple components decorated with same form name.

Let's say we have `SimpleForm1` and `SimpleForm2`. When rendering Only `SimpleForm1` with the `name` field validation works as expected, as well as when rendering `SimpleForm2` with the `surname` field. But when rendering them both on a single page validation for `SimpleForm1` is broken.

The question is how to avoid such behaviour and make both validation functions work.

[Here is a fiddle which illustrates my problem](https://jsfiddle.net/5cmyzpvs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use same names for multiple forms. 
As i understand you need to dynamically add form inputs(`SimpleForm2` in your example) and have possibility to submit both forms with one button. 
If yes, so you can add just an input to first form, you don't need second form.

Form:

```
const SimpleFormComponent1 = props => {
    const {handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, renderBoth} = props;
    const onSubmit = (values) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values));
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            ...
            {
                renderBoth &&
                <Field
                    name="surname"
                    type="text"
                    component={renderField}
                    label="Surname"
                    validate={validateSurname}
                />
            }
            ...
        </form>
    )
};
```

Render function:

```
render() {
        const {renderBoth} = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className='forms'>
                    <SimpleForm renderBoth={renderBoth}/>
                </div>
                <button
                    type='button'
                    onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    {renderBoth ? 'Show Single' : 'Show Both'}
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

> [Updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/gxup4hed/)

Comment: Sure, I think that is the best approach but I had to deal with some existing code. And yep, me and my colleagues decided to refactor it just like this. I was more interested in the source of the problem. As I imagine to myself, both forms are rendered at same page, both fields are registered in redux-from so theoretically form submission should cause validation for all of them, but it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1**

I was having interference with `invalid` and `valid` props of the Redux Form because I wrote the `validate` function on `ReduxForm()` in every file of my main form component.

You haven't to change the form name to solve this. You have to put the validation function on the parent component.

---

Here is an example:

[CONTEXT]

I have 3 Components:
 1. Main component to put the form ('editUserForm') elements (, , ...)
 2. Field1 of the form ('editUserForm') that changes user's complete name.
 3. Field2 of the form ('editUserForm') that changes user's email.

[SOLUTION]

**MAIN COMPONENT**:
Inside the main frame, you call reduxForm() (*it creates a decorator with which you use redux-form to connect your form component to Redux. More info here [Redux Form docs](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/)*). Your code would be like this:

```
import...

class MainFrame ... {
   ...
   <form ...>
         <Field1 />
         <Field2 />
   </form>
   ...
}

const validate ({ name, email }, props) => {
    errors={}

    // Validation around Field1
    if (name === ...) errors.name = "Name error passed to Field1 component";

    // Validation around Field2
    if (email === ...) errors.email= "Email error passed to Field2 component";

    return errors;
}
...
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'editUserForm',
    validate // <--------- IMPORTANT: Only put this function on the parent component.
})(MainComponent);
```

**FIELD1 & FIELD2 COMPONENTS**:
This code is for the 2 children components. IMPORTANT: You call reduxForm() **without** `validate` [Redux Form docs](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-validate-values-object-props-object-gt-errors-object-code-optional-) synchronous function.

```
import...

class MainFrame ... {
   ...
   const { invalid } = this.props;
   ...
   <inputs
       error={invalid}
   >
         ...
   </input>
   ...
}

// IMPORTANT: Don't put the validation function in Field1 and Field2 components, because their local validations will interfere with the validation of the other Field component.
reduxForm({
    form: 'editUserForm'
})
```

Now, the props: `valid` and `invalid` will work perfectly inside the children components (`Field1` and `Field2`).

---

**SOLUTION 2**

User Redux Form `FormSection` ([docs](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/formsection.md/)) to split forms into smaller components that are reusable across multiple forms.